# How does SMTP facilitate sending spam?

Tags: spam, smtp

My friend tells me that there are exist weakness of the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) that make make it easy to send spam.

Is this true?

Comment: Without knowing which specific weakness your friend was talking about and what they mean with "easier" (easier compared to which alternative medium?) this question can only be answered by guessing.

Comment: You should ask your friend what weaknesses he believes still exist in SMTP; you can then ask here if those are still valid weaknesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no weakness in the SMTP protocol itself, but there is a problem of trust.  You can send a letter by snail mail and simply write a different sender on the letter. The letter will still be delivered to the recipient even if the sender is spoofed. And exactly the same can be done with SMTP, which is just the electronic way of delivering letters.

The problem is not the protocol itself, neither with electronic nor with snail mail. The problem is that the recipient believes that the sender is not spoofed, because usually it is not. With snail mail this can be worked around with a signature or a seal, but this is not part of the letter delivery itself. With electronic mail you can also have signatures and encryption for the mail, but this is also not part of the mail delivery itself. Have a look at [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) or [S/MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) for the electronic ways of doing signatures and seals.

And the other "weakness" of SMTP is that electronic mail is just very cheap. Thus you can easily and cheaply spam lots of recipients, much cheaper than you could do with snail mail.